# React onChange event will not fire on custom Input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a custom input component like so:

```js
import * as React from "react";

const Input = (props) => {
  
  return (
    <input
      type={props.type}
      name={props.name}
      className={props.className}
      value={props.value}
      onChange={props.onChange}
    />
  );
};
export default Input;
```

I'm trying to handle the onChange event but it doesn't fire here:

```js
import Input from "../../Components/Input";
...
<Input
  type="text"
  onChange={e => console.log(`${e.target.value}`)}
  id="subject"
  className="rounded-sm px-4 py-3 mt-3 focus:outline-none w-full border bg-transparent border- 
    gray-300"
  placeholder="Subject"
/>
```

I have tried passing the event to the custom input via props and also tried handling the event directly in the Input component.

Desired behavior to change state with useState:

```js
const [subject, setSubject] = useState('');
...
onChange={e => setSubject(e.target.value)}
```

Input then becomes readonly when I add these lines

Comment: in your `Input` component, you have not used the passed `onChange` anywhere, that's why it is not firing up. Include `<input onChange={props.onChange} ... ` also.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a custom component like your Input, you have to specify all the props, as you can see you are giving an onChange prop to your Input component without passing it to the input tag.

```
import * as React from "react";

const Input = (props) => {
  
  return (
    <input
      type={props.type}
      name={props.name}
      className={props.className}
      value={value}
      onChange={props.onChange}
    />
  );
};
export default Input;
```

Comment: Changing this and adding the event via props seems to change the input to readonly, and event still doesn't fire

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle your `onChange()` from your `Input` component. Otherwise, it won't fire directly.

```
import * as React from "react";
const Input = (props) => {
  return (
    <input
       type={props.type}
       name={props.name}
       className={props.className}
       value={value}
       onChange={ev => props.onChange}
    />
 );
};
export default Input;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. You can give the state for input in parent component and update from child accordingly.

Input.js

```
import * as React from "react";

const Input = (props) => {
  
  return (
    <input
      type={props.type}
      name={props.name}
      className={props.className}
      value={props.value}
      onChange={e => props.handleInputData(e.target.value)}

    />
  );
};
export default Input;
```

Second component

```
import React from 'react'

export default function secondComponent() {
  const [inputData,handleInputData] = useState("");
  return (
    <div>
      <Input
        type="text"
        id="subject"
        className="rounded-sm px-4 py-3 mt-3 focus:outline-none w-full border bg-transparent border- 
          gray-300"
        placeholder="Subject"
        handleInputData={handleInputData}
        value={inputData}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Still no luck trying this, tried passing down the event via props and field is still readonly? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

in your Input component, you have not used the passed onChange anywhere, that's why it is not firing up

```
<Input
  .
  .
  .
  onChange={props.onChange}
/>
```

Also ,one important step, the value should be the state of `useEffect` as the `updater`. if you don't do this, the value will not update, and it will be `readonly`

so,  pass props as follows:

```
const [subject, setSubject] = useState('');

<Input
  .
  .
  value={subject}
  onChange={e => setSubject(e.target.value)}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions,

React package was out-dated and running an update seems to have fixed my problems!